# Eliminate duplicate rows containing blanks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a condition where I have one header and multiple lines for an item.
I am attempting to add the values from the line join to my header query.
Valid values for this `PGM_CD` field are `S, L, V, Blank` etc.

If a line has a value on one line and blank on the others, I need to report the actual value at the header level and not blank values.
ie - line 1 is blank, line 2 is V, I want to report V.
Since blank is a valid value on some, I can't eliminate blanks in my subquery completely.

How do I interrogate all the lines to find that they are either all blank, where I would report blank at the header level or that there is a value on one of the lines in which case I would report that value at the header?

Here's a subset of my query

```
SELECT 
hdr.field1
hdr.field2
hdr.field3
au.PGM_CD   (this field can have the blanks, v, l, etc. values)
 FROM HEADER hdr
 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT l.ID, PGM_CD
  FROM LINE l 
  LEFT JOIN AUTH a
  ON l.ID = a.ID) AS au
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data (preferably ddl+dml so that we can use it to test, a link to an sql fiddle would be nice also) and desired output to your question?

Comment: What's the relationship between your HEADER table and the LINE and/or AUTH tables in your subquery?

Comment: Maybe by using MAX? If that doesn't help you might want to take a peek at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: There is one header for multiple lines.  The field I am trying to get to, PGM_CD, is on the auth table which has to be joined to via the line table. Once I have the value from the auth table for each line, I just want to report it one time at the header.  All the rest of the report is at the header level.  So I basically need to read all lines and if all lines are blank, return blank at the header level.  If any of the lines has a value other than blank, return that value at the header level.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: What I am currently getting is two iterations of the header id, one with a blank value and one with an actual value.

Comment: Example:  Header ID 12345 returns two rows, one with blank PGM_CD, one with V PGM_CD.

Comment: Unfortunately, your article link is blocked by my company's filter.

Comment: Examples:                                                                                            CL_ID PGM_CD
5001 
5001 S

Answer (score 0):

Use a `group by` and `max`:

```
SELECT 
   hdr.field1
   hdr.field2
   hdr.field3
   max(au.PGM_CD) AS PGM_CD
FROM HEADER hdr
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT l.ID, PGM_CD
        FROM LINE l 
        LEFT JOIN AUTH a
        ON l.ID = a.ID) AS au
  ON hdr.ID = au.ID
GROUP BY hdr.ID, hdr.field1, hdr.field2, hdr.field3
```

Comment: @sammy68 appreciate if you would mark as answer and upvote in that case